# Gerund question: "I could see it going down the drain."

Tags: sentence-structure, gerunds

[image]

> I could see it going down the drain.

In this sentence, I want to ask whether "going" is a gerund or "going down" is a phrasal verb.

And is the word "see" modifying "it" or is "going" modifying "it"?
Please explain properly because I am a novice.

Comment: This is a catenative construction where "going" is a gerund-participle verb heading the gerund-participial clause "going down the drain", which functions as complement of "see". "It" is the syntactic object of "see", and the _understood_ subject of the subordinate clause.

Comment: You mean that gerund participle clause is modifying SEE  and please explain which one is the subordinate clause

Comment: No: the gerund-participial clause is not a modifier, but a complement of "see". the g-p clause is the subordinate one.

Comment: Going down the drain is no fun. However, it can happen to your reputation. And I doubt the first comment will be understood by the OP. Those kinds of comments are 100% useless to "novices."

Answer (score 1):

I see X. X is the object of see.
x = "it going down the drain" is a clause that serves as the object of the sentence.

Separately, if we look at the sentence this clause would be based on: "It is going down the drain", we see that "is going" is the verb, and "down the drain" is the object clause "Where is it going? Down the drain."

Putting everything together:

"I see [it going (down the drain)]."

Answer (score 0):

> In this sentence, I want to ask whether "going" is a gerund or "going down" is a phrasal verb.

Neither. "Going" is the present particle. A gerund is a form that functions like a noun. For example, in "The going down of the water", "going" is a gerund (that's an awkward construction, used just to give an example of "going" as a gerund). The phrase "down the drain" is functioning as an adverb. BTW, gerunds can be formed from phrasal verbs, so presenting this as an either/or is inaccurate.

> And is the word "see" modifying "it" or is "going" modifying "it"?

The phrase "going down the drain" functions as an adjective modifying "it". "See" is a verb that takes "it" as the object.